# SQL query result load in excel sheet

Tags: sql-server, excel

My question is what is the query for fetching the result from SQL server and storing it into excel file which has more than 1,000,000 rows, where excel has its limits of rows also.

I had a question if we use statistics on the query and store it in the temp database can it be load the output file to the excel.

Comment: There isn't a single query to do this, you'll need to use some kind of looping process in your ETL process to put rows that exceed the maximum number in a different file or worksheet. How you do this is quite a broad subject on it's own, especially when we don't know what your ETL solution is.

Comment: As for the latter question, I don't follow what you're asking. Statistic can't be stored in a different table; a table has it's own statistics, and you can't load those into an Excel file.

Comment: Side note: Please don't use non-English words like "lakh", it has little meaning to those who don't speak the language.

Comment: Have you considered that if you need to export more than 1 million rows then perhaps Microsoft Excel files are not the correct mechanism? If you're needing to transport data between RDBMS/statistics systems there are probably much better file formats to use.

Comment: with Power Pivot you can load more than 1Million rows

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.